# Reading XML as string vs Reading XML as DOM in java

Tags: java, xml, string, dom

I am new to java and wanted to know which method of reading XML is better. Reading XML as string and reading XML as DOM ( or any other method). Just curious to know if reading the XML as string is better than DOM or else any way to read XML efficiently.

Comment: As a general point, no-one can say whether X or Y is better without knowing (a) what you are trying to achieve and (b) how you measure goodness (performance? lines of code? maintainability?). In this particular case it's not even clear what you mean by "reading XML as a string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading an XML file as a string makes only sense, if you doesn't need any content processing. E.g. when a webserver sends the XML file as is to the client. In such a case it would be contraproductive to parse the XML.

But in all other cases the XML should be parsed. It is especially not a good idea to manipulate an XML string via regular expressions.

The most basic thing you get from parsing is the certainty of **well formedness**. The parsing process will only complete for real XML documents.

Well formedness means:

- Only one root node.
- Always matching begin and end elements.
- No special characters like `<`, `>` and `&` used in text. Must be escaped accordingly.
- Characters in texts (text nodes and attributes) are properly encoded (according to the declared encoding or as unicode entities).

Additionally you can **validate** the XML documet against a DTD or XSD Schema. So you can be sure about the document structure.

If you have a parsed DOM document you can

- access and manipulate the nodes
- query some nodes with XPath
- tranform the document via XSLT
- query via XQuery (with 3rd party libs like Saxon)
- unmarshall to a Java object via JAXB

But this is only suitable for small to medium sized documents because the whole document tree must be hold entirely in memory.

Besides DOM there are other technologies to process large XML document without the need to hold the document in memory:

- SAX: Low-level API to process XML with callbacks. You implent a handler class and the parser calls your handler method for each open tag, close tag, text node, etc.
- StAX: More modern pull API (low level event API and higher level streaming API) including a simple to use write API.

Answer (score 1):

- Special character are converted back to original form while you red it as DOM.
  like `&lt;` converted to <
  And others like `&lt; (<), &amp; (&), &gt; (>), &quot; ("), and &apos; (')`
- It is easy to process the data inside XML in DOM
- Validate automatically when you read as DOM (i.e. You can not convert in DOM if your XML is not valid)